# Pass array of floats to fragment shader via texture

Tags: glsl, webgl, pixi.js

I am trying to pass an array of floats (in my case an audio wave) to a fragment shader via texture. It works but I get some imperfections as if the value read from the 1px height texture wasn't reliable.

[image]

This happens with many combinations of bar widths and amounts.

I get the value from the texture with:

```
precision mediump float;
...
uniform sampler2D uDisp;
...
void main(){
  ...
  float columnWidth = availableWidth / barsCount;
  float barIndex = floor((coord.x-paddingH)/columnWidth);
  float textureX = min( 1.0, (barIndex+1.0)/barsCount );
  float barValue = texture2D(uDisp, vec2(textureX, 0.0)).r;
  ...
```

If instead of the value from the texture I use something else the issue doesn't seem to be there.

```
barValue = barIndex*0.1;
```

[image]

Any idea what could be the issue? Is using a texture for this purpose a bad idea?
I am using [Pixi.JS](http://www.pixijs.com/) as WebGL framework, so I don't have access to low level APIs.

With a gradient texture for the data and many bars the problems becomes pretty evident.

[image]

**Update:** Looks like the issue relates to the consistency of the value of textureX.
Trying different formulas like `barIndex/(barsCount-1.0)` results in less noise. Wrapping it on a `min` definitely adds more noise.

Comment: Is it any better if you use: float textureX = min( 1.0, (barIndex+0.5)/barsCount )? (that's +0.5 instead of +1.0)? It'd mean you sample from the centre of the texel instead of the edge. Also, you should use precision highp float; instead of mediump.

Comment: @Columbo unfortunately none of those changes make a difference.

Comment: Also, make sure you don't generate/use mipmaps for your texture.

Answer (score 1):

Turned out the issue wasn't in reading the values from the texture, but was in the drawing. Instead of using IFs I switched to step and the problem went away.

```
vec2 topLeft = vec2(
  paddingH + (barIndex*columnWidth) + ((columnWidth-barWidthInPixels)*0.5),
  top
);
vec2 bottomRight = vec2(
  topLeft.x + barWidthInPixels,
  bottom
);
vec2 tl = step(topLeft, coord);
vec2 br = 1.0-step(bottomRight, coord);
float blend = tl.x * tl.y * br.x * br.y;
```

I guess comparisons of floats through IFs are not very reliable in shaders.

Comment: And that's exactly why MVCEs are required

Comment: @LJᛃ MVCE being?

Answer (score 0):

Generally `mediump` is insufficient for texture coordinates for any non-trivial texture, so where possible use `highp`. This isn't always available on some older GPUs, so depending on the platform this may not solve your problem.

If you know you are doing 1:1 mapping then also use GL_NEAREST rather than GL_LINEAR, as the quantization effect will more likely hide some of the precision side-effects.

Given you probably know the number of columns and bars you can probably pre-compute some of the values on the CPU (e.g. precompute `1/columns` and pass that as a uniform) at fp32 precision. Passing in small values between 0 and 1 is always much better at preserving floating point accuracy, rather than passing in big values and then dividing out.

Comment: I will definitely try to precompute some variables, thanks! Not sure if in Pixi I can change GL_LINEAR to GL_NEAREST.

Comment: I can't agree on your first paragraph, usually `mediump` is plenty for sampling from textures, also note that precision qualifiers have no effect on desktop platforms which (since its not explicitly mentioned in the question) I assume the OP is experiencing this issue on.

Comment: FP16 gives you 11 bits of fractional mantissa precision for values close to 1.0, which means a `mediump` ST texture coordinate between 0 and 1 has enough bits to address a texture which is 2048 texels wide (it does better with values close to zero, but this is the limit close to 1). For decent `GL_LINEAR` filtering you generally want to keep at least 16 sub-texel addressing steps, so that reduces 2048 to 256. It gets worse if your input UV coordinates are using any kind of wrap mode.

Comment: Input data in the vertex buffers can be `mediump`, but you really really want to use `highp` in the shaders for varying interpolation and any computation on texture coordinates.